# Solve huge symbolic system of linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, symbolic

I have a system of 76 symbolic linear equations (i.e. some coefficients are symbolic) with a sparse coefficient matrix. However, neither `Solve[]` nor `LinearSolve[]` can solve this system in a reasonable amount of time (I have not received an answer in an hour).

On the other hand, Maple gives me the correct answer in a few seconds.

The 76 linear equations `$equations` in 76 `$coefficients` are (also can be found [here](http://labfiles.milaboratory.com/equations.mathematica).):

```
$equations = Uncompress["1:eJztXUuPHVcRdsbxOCCEEIsIKRISWURZzu3nDHt2WaCIP2BQLFkYInDy570IzNx+1a3qOqe+73S3HeVmYcczp/q8qurUu/709++/ff3Ns2fP3n36+Mc3b9798Prm6V8vHv/4y39+fPX29e+nX/717Y/vll/+7c2/vhv/+dnjH9+++uHN9/9+9fbN/x7/e3P+8fPHP15VNQ7SwyDNHQ5SvX5+ASJ+\ 1/Xvnv7xXauGeF99LrZ7hvyn/ngAsg9DfvL4DwFZP7CQzR0NWbH7bO8xyFtztjUO2WOQ9mwDkOcTWuaczpaArDBIe7b160891B6HfNe+e/n0s3+8evvqv3dvHv/3mab7L5/hdL8s5aSJ+DxgvI5T/nPqTKomuAIB0sIgdZSNCJDAwtRe6i4P8tPlaTb4LM0DDNLiJ9Z2MHqfRmI8wZBVE4Y0uMBC1nc\ 0ZHy1BkHYORt6zuaBhWzps23j+/xJcxf6KWhYtjzhEA5Z009BHV+txr4uDPn0kwtew87ZxB9LjQn02bbzPtVz8/RyDV8D3zDJqeCN8MxtQekNNqKJu8H5Ac1rF/xRy7wt2sOpQu7v5rwS/BIqYtfDXOxxnUBpz0xZZyW53xFUsEiMYaFIgAQkHK2OBcQVBRKWPYQ4Tys8Ez8lVKUTqyo1ccVOK1n0nC\ 24z01eufhbpU/odMBbpZUses75rbpSaVrpjlOphoxjr4NJBH3T5heASjUkuE+KSnmJ0uGAhCkElCgpKvUkylUq/XWCSoWJo8ZtmC1Owa0WUM960mjDrNZtmHJIkx/SOkPeL0Mesl/pnYm8y5CHgiGAPJvUNX6VuMaVb7+8RJGT5pzSjhuQU7VmGbWRS4tmHuTmkgrrwCxa6AkYhF5c7qW+nwyn8J4iR\ nxrKh0u+z6Bwvd5/AzQykgI+jWTQ3pnyHuzFjNk2VJ/coYsqN3X+SHOcgMqUNwoY9CYNs/RWnNNz1nzJsF7WjWOGxMdnwChX4LCNeVv0ZgQN88pw14dn1OzN948d0+LJ7Qwtfh41EOygdmqJmS7OBk5BLiH2aqOygubUHW7vpFLiW+kKf35C4e385aYqewQoWh5L9LyllRV9hWovIfCriXxro0+0NRE\ jbeW5SuT47HLmqu+KEKa0z0uf2kxRwryAXFOO+uierUACYhzWk3BfZUtLmcyLsGA1dzcGS1z0PTe0HJOQ0srLe1MbGk5p8A9F9+nljniL6qWOeKvuHr/m7ico+mVdiYC2qnGBFq2KnCV7elhwhUNgAAd0t1DeGpwnx/PD5qkjSJlasrbP4yNImAQ1k+neAdb7UyLaNiLsDJptWVKeO/JVmKII1tFDgw\ jLHluqWv8uoiwIuKM0dtwCaiZ2e+owOHmpUBQlxa58aCuiFnJKmmjjArbvxr88B8Ze1hw0vzZkN+yku4uQX552gICWnnRzDEf7BrnpdW/0wHRWgYlafZPi4MNfSuAIGnQ8wBx0DEp7hrnpU1QtOcIiNbSkHTkFGCC0gIzfSuA8Kqx734/ya0mSDfOLhxGs4ssrZ0ZEZBSTpI2e+Fiy0AKr6JC6BLV9O\ BbmWrvoTPbSZnWujv6LWTeiGFTNOtkWIqcMh8d9nnRRXd4LH+nBTGhZnRRiWvhY31gBYrF91As4ah64CA4hnU0Q+riDiIF2dMyU087pXranNXT5qyOjtvq4iGaGtHic6rXuWfCQi/OloB0XCBbvM49cdU0MfQ7vs49HhlZQCeOm7A0lhp6loe3FxdKgEgCM9kB3m7PC5x9MG8SZy8tZtpBI3/Xr375V\ 9kvn5/2qKXl/OMzRNSLs0CYyLJFgKo63n25DGkdYS6wGcJON+xpAlzLjhQjAsmR+TDAD3dTi9X1lA/Ncy/T+n8TQ5q8YbZxvpK/tvh965NJmWV/iWntcdu4MoQCae0aMp7WruR6IK1dQQJp7RoyntbupF7j0sEhYVZOyYBd7U0aMi7RqlsJpLXPPGrnZCiCiMORsBdEjIKYCNj8sV5rVUQRj2B7R9Sq\ KDQi27PdtVaFZwq+Uun16T3q6XU44K5Pr9Zt6cTDQ55ex+lXlAzVQErNMC9BW8ZzgLnIPRVGZG/kdSXP0S4jVOL+B3MobIRK+5C6xpvYNdqsp+V39X0JgpxwPSdcDuD845szGiYU5fy1VXkUqp2blUPyKXdNPFnOnAlrGWlS6PFCXqLjprm0eQ9/17Mb5HLsbG8rMbIETkNHFwm7DBQbd4ZIMJcqf6e\ u53JBQddzaUPoU/wHdG7K42LNLEneUmZmCUe/CdmPeGxwY06bsGx6UYp5eeTE6xsNDdnSUiI9Z0trni24Wj4m3Z7t/iWj7NkeGpwzr9Y3s0ysbuuoArWUSFSBcrV2ASLWPvMoqxCz4J6zLlEJscdTnnvCf017+Ds6WrCL++k1JO027OhAfCAewYnYwD38HU2oXZytaCKh3aMdrfD2O2aIdsRG6NCTbs\ uN6G9Hq+RQdOJQmOGYZVEFYZ1dgGixOjILe38tHYWHKt52znxUwR/l2Y/e40k7ntW74W+Trnpe1RmkHvUb6QBNhVS6Wu0yxPXtLkM8rWNFw04Uxzh5eca3ZrlMzrNV2FI5z3f5Id5XhLjU5b9SkFwtDHzepq1+mVhLk19Lm7+ANl+dpM0nnbf5SindfEeK7XxqScmkzyyLOXnZ+LdmyPrxCsILZLevW\ VO0tHv5Yk/v77rEOPOZPep5Y3loG5Q1CmSEmXQNeGFMze59yhlpHwh+yExOfyLN0+SZxRXrQwsG8dlafMoHn5VGCx4FBYPoWykoNUDPWVAwgHfhxU0sTz/hMsQ09vH1vI9oRKELI9C3UlDeYMsMMZO0hZMun1C6ZQy6ZgvRYJ8t+IGbIQZqi/rZgB7hVT0mMgmx62EumpUxJC6nzKuKfyiigm5UK00a\ VsRkhRs2onnwUuTF92RsrMvnIjZWa7Ia/j40g4s3TPE5UbwNiS4OxOd+AbZW4xyg7Z50QSLA1urYsUtyv7Z/dCK21u3cB3sajfFaRQU+Cc/W+hu5h/GlJYqt4dWGbZzUjaawpK0vX9/QjZMSX/ECbpYhaJwUZSJ2zLUEJB8IG373UwKXMJ2d9BqkuTFfV7LJx0K1Hg6IIZ5VTQyZJtohcITpbQAlaw0\ 7IEASZlGvZHteZLr2NclC0p0hDulronUusAaNPVuCD5X3NfEDR5pwfk6eyZ2VpUTB9yrvjaryKY11PtjXS2GVQ6oUjyvLcmCC46IV1wQnxUFaPMbqGvmWm/OQyDfeRKpWC0S+8SbSwpqq9mz3yEX6WVOpOieASjU+xCnGwSRCtKHnBKjUwSQ8DbjABQJSDEWlfKk73jXgcMDtyqwKzO4dapWnhVc4jV\ CyiRmGQSK93wgXuGbMXVxPurk83Uj7au2veJhlrIlboZ9gSrAmIlJ2KD4sqJ82p/LFUoHa+QbhDnCiW/Qj5yxoZctHDNJnCzTFVlQGNMUulPMsDhFyHt+IkC+zyvcIoOdEG41aHCpRyNVjtoH1PNIU24CwZLRpU2xN3IH20AaklAeZV2ytuxDusIxkwyoHt8mGNaeeMs5H4obBPFa5G9ZrT98PkDq7L\ FZOuXcX7khGlAbBMyGNHz0PEslH0g5+2orb0UUiOtrY09FlNHpajexpNRLwkesTopMcAB+5ovQtsorgW9nR2POzplKN93R3aoBK9Zy0sQegUk1rtEkWoFKN96CvhaJSPSdt7NkiHoXlgOtUehEBFyc9vS8iAg436IQJPBHOFsD/h5nQlagszhQ3wzARcHT0RUeLbwURcLRu0tHGgYIa5nQl8o5W8Q/h\ G5rMaKV5zxrmHa4xFqC0ozFuEgGHp93y2L7cpVrmSgRcfUwf1ERxay8GRw7x6v1Ioc4ZYo4lGQEX16DNodCGS5ofFjTDnPjEVqXXU6WfHrYIqTfiHA5SzZiy/uRLbhhNCxRPPe6kiTRFsbVIYBDcHFRQvoRvvMD3nuAbsdDR0oBAUWguoEQRjWh0GD/QFKXQXLCTQKHv7dBuPTsmpEWaohiQUgpLCxT\ wHiJNUbQ/6X58wIwxXYgCXtE+czNJUSAvlrj+aTGE90/T3legl4u2ydMJNPFeLvmOK8NSPkyB0uVrbjTqMsTzt6zU3SCqQ4KcV2xqAnRjg08Tbmdv62Xstj5UvWFB9PESkOqg0TwSuZ7sSbfhky6svx6QCxUIU38dJ8pr/XUf8uNufaJWe0j9dQWJdkmwZ7t1/fVfMJVqfLj2MsnsE+2SQFGpwwF37W\ XClztxOODWvUxeSCrV1p+E1Wfy6Ghj1mxu2/cRj0QVa1rH3d8NzlHaqCohSPWaH5mDBPfJB3Las901P1I/4kfkR2oBqdvvEf9ZU6nGB1p4BahU0xod5QJQqcYHek40i5miUocDErRGG5cLgqbpyJo0lV6YHka7xWj9qxpH0r0spTZJCsPjvl7G89TsHUaK2zkOClDDu2VcA9Ryq0XDSO3Z7uoXUuzik\ EATfULlfqHzYq5UmsOka7C3S9/8amkx+CMP9nY4YEE4WFE4iSZHEU7SrH74i8SH8weFZfOMgkNi+QHWsDjaz7uK8p8FImBLNAlIKAQUSHuGiHK4BYKoMUo7soHqpGqVdIIUE2Iy3BYLyMS6DnfHAvKlW2nRBSj6+vQTSWlELIy8ST5hDQZkxDN5kzigEzlaGHozcjh0MUws2eUVb7AL9Wn8EmkGMOHb\ 6nv3VWIX0h8QMFYt9DGA4LGP1UPcNGYSxOHHujnFTWTGVpEHealAiB5LgT29ULOkWikHymB4Bdhu5hmmQqOJehtTJHaqA4zXX0dMlO871Od7/UyBU3jl2Coe/qTuraLfMaBUhmOxI8pW8JB8Qy96n0CdVxWCWsXLNGlORnsePoSfpKAaJB/sQO+z3VJS0HSIN1sAiN5hFxuLPCMC4suhs34qL+vnsuD\ FWbQwtTzNZ1JPSSA00i3UKSqCeo+AXQvTNs4ud6M+bFl/wS+wAbdXxTwvOl4LHObmPKTAoRboDytPZc/20N5H+QbcU+vKfATvb5890w5Lo36tKU1Tlb92ZjST4uHSmyvvC2E+3zfSlfcXJu3K+2IiT96/NctNrGWR9xVf+uziVNdfL3Fb3sHcmiGJXbvvjnhUAu1K87qS++7Yktf5d2cF/+ox6s1k+U\ pHeT9T0UQTw9+JnF0vT3YjfVMMSfYBHYbkL2tK1EmhaBPCv4GvmnYPAi/yaUNuM9xb85UUAnpfsX0lUtiV7907t47drFuGlm3l7/I14CvvhMUQz2KynE2d75YxdQFeryT/58Rm81aliMNJmYisw0lIUQEJ8OknmMPpk0uIgMi4LPkMEXA4KYjAPl5eQgQcTgoiYWpzi+wFcEsMySNxnZ8o0A6hyZOC2\ 0tcDPGYOdZ3YZMONW5fc0EHeXnD7Wv+3tx0qml5vq22y8oDgkKAlUOyhNvX3OJL6s3IP5VuX3NOrtnmcUoo7t5y3xusw43NgCvacWDifiHaLca0ARz4OAvIVEkYuDoLSJvPAFe0E1SAe5SZgg7yJnH/LlNUWd4k7v5k0gblTe7hxIWCuUGaWyfWPRzq+CXSDMDpDTlYTS6Vc93O3nwlJZWfPHZuPpLX\ RgojwrQiKMK7KtwlHMn81J6AgGSrXGV11KorQIjmF9EAAZkiiHv5ibZLtHeyYoI0xlti56zpOWu+jQTfk5yub9bw0Xq0dxJNc7f3iXub6/icmmz5lg50CyM0td7e5x4O05rIW6abW9fOq7aFC7vGC/4UUPVHVl8bz6WIlLXTINf0JQ/yI6+vzacvOUknRE3vI+prqxP62KrgfzRUek1fQun7iF4Vmr7\ BSH2KSh0OuGvxSSh9KVkObVn46WEWJocHevz3HLlcT2ZS9Y3J1pLTbVPR3wE9aU6jxvXYRPmU2dkc+KySnZtoJUgBElCPX1zebaRwtQ4QwfX2SBNEHWNuXO3CI5L3zrje+G2iQcSQpHlmGJK3/Lve+PdmRwGDvMVtUh3gmzM2fPR3ce1vIvqbtjsUtFhk7PkX90nYAOLvjm49GLc7aD5Gy5VALXeNCb\ REWtDucM8ugTjRAwTokO4exowG79vI84PGuZHVdocmfsl8JxnbnS97HPD0u65zEaOTjw9zXed2RykXcd7TH4+CisqIo2xYnWZ2Nezobt7ZMLEWjSZHXm4dXxJUKEXYPIhO1MFT+SI+DlP8DDfGRWtpyTQenNzXaxaMAj++gn2yG021U/xF5jNUeP8MLT8AjbMN1tC8mM7MA3wlBl1o2YzPI4zL2j9p7\ sJKWBXvE+ILGNO+koKiqny9RTqQ5ZBKjRpyy/Q7rQsSpUX4Uhb7lE6YXlYY23le64jEyfDu5GfPAgsUZ3CGCIjPeg42SocONysOiyrql5G3v6f6ckXFtZt50Yn+C25Y9DLEjXnOqxaRjWJcT2xqAlxLARMjAhlgX2N3pVMhJ6txQFg0ryLOU6BKTZeqCdG3Z7KA4ybYcPHclCi+HFVEFDfvIryCOYkP\ 14mMSL6SMZWy9PIdh+i3D3hstgufog2ggGDvCGVHBkEBgr0jlBGQccFeMSJAsDfWA1aELOh5QBtdC3qa8CWa6WJphxR3dpTDPeThiGC/mdViU8HeyNp7GlEcLp0xEZ9FHsiSFJXvtQjs22xP+SIkbpLdMsTLfQuL9QeWUCwu9bdVJ19T70z+br2Vb0oxHCST80pNZoBI+83LNSfPpfB+niCZgSgOKzV\ iQrw9uj9Fwy0ECF7ZJRJ9oUBMZZeArnIt25KZEyjbol0vdFD3IWVbtAwFKt72bAvKtlypNIRJRCfFOMVoSBrvASp1MImgb5qnFASmMEmYKJVqfQXkDBSVai2ysBL8qlgpftXvUH0tXI5WSJl47HXEUatBArWTcAZx7f+UhaS70RUYF47o/6Rv5UOYCOZ9utXXpuoZZZ2q8+QVaUWvWYVOg5WKUqKxuN\ dY3jsvuUjsduVasyc9V17aqie4qTkWYHJE59pElTIvdDqyEMKbNK4ne9JtHz3plYpup7FaYFU5zqLLvNKBtqs8Vnb3WXOKG/0thuRr83T5cix9vjSMG0O+VkFc4dRnK6dqSpIJ6d6zTdyaIUwxIVuSbKcaPwIBpysoqqEgSD3SZcBU9Q6SugDB3XCEp5JwN4bFOQGCNxyKuBJNkW7cEMAX0qYt7ED1/\ M0ccgXOMdqVB1TPd6qt4w45oHq+plBaIvwQ/UsLpFC+CTm9z02r55uC9jjp8klTO4bvRarnG5BS7rVurPi8aCORVGtFfB2emhnpR6nTgaMiuliYfoSFGNBDDeZGIQ2+446Oke6YOnZS9CXwqqMj1zsal3t+tUxFuouz/UjbW2ryosM35vzwHTh3p/WzCEgpMezBuTucc/PY3jlvKR+vPDzRRLI4FLE8\ zkKLhDRjKUg1dYMN/g/TGBw4"];
$coefficients = Uncompress["1:eJwtzLtNQ1EQRdEnoBE6sOd3TQ+O6AACJCKCR//C4q5k9iRnvX7+vH/dj+M4Xx7n/n3+nk+P5+Oyc92Jndypnd6ZnbVz23k7n//nF71qaGpp6+jSm/KCF7zgBS94wQte8IIXvOQlL3nJS17ykpe85CWveMUrXvGKV7ziFa94xWte85rXvOY1r3nNa17zhje84Q1veMMb3vCGN7zFW7zFW7zFW/0H\ Ks1gug=="];
```

and I try the following code to solve:

```
$result = Solve[$equations,$coefficients]
```

or

```
$matrix = CoefficientArrays[$equations, $coefficients];
$result = LinearSolve[$matrix[[2]], $matrix[[1]]]
```

Is there any way to solve this system with Mathematica in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: If possible, please try to post code directly in your question to make it permanent and give viewers direct feedback what awaits them. It is also good practice to provide all relevant code to show what you already tried.

Comment: I think you should use sparse arrays for sparse equations, like in `LinearSolve @@ Reverse@CoefficientArrays[$equations, $coefficients]` though I doubt it's going to give you much speed up

Comment: Can you say anything about the values of the constants `scalar0`, `k`, etc. Adding some assumptions might make a difference.

Comment: I tried to use `LinearSolve @@ Reverse@CoefficientArrays[$equations, $coefficients]` but steel I have no solution. The constants `scalar0` and others are arbitrary (not even real) constants.

Comment: Can you at least be certain that the determinant is non-zero? i.e. `1 + e5 scalar0 != 0`, `-1 + 2 e5 scalar0 + 6 e6 scalar0 != 0`, etc. *Mathematica* might require this as an assumption.

Comment: Thank you, Corey, but I tried this with a number of assumptions and nothing happened. I even tried to take some arbitrary exact values of these parameters and found that `a5`, `a6` etc. are zeros, then I passed this result as assumptions to `Solve[]` but steel have no solution. Moreover, the function `Det[]` is also can not up to the task in a reasonable time.

Comment: You mean you can't get `Det[]` to run? 
`problem = CoefficientArrays[equations, coefficients];
Det[problem[[2]]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: Yes, but in my case `Det[]` takes more then 10 minutes and then I stop it without waiting for an answer, since Mathematica takes to much memory (despite the fact that I have rather powerful machine).

Comment: That sounds like a more serious problem with your system. `Det[]` of the same matrix is running instantly on my relatively old work machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9504/discussion-between-stanislav-poslavsky-and-corey-kelly)

Comment: It seems that this example is sensitive to some heuristic internal settings that involve use of Together and related. In the version currently under development it gives a result, with leaf count around 100 M, in under a half minute on my desk top. In version 9, same machine, it gives a result around 2/3 that size, in about 45 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! The result should be very simple, since I know it from physics. Maple gives a very simple answer.

Comment: My guess is the simplification heuristics in the row reduction code are not working too well for this example.

Comment: I tweaked some of the heuristics and it gives considerable improvement. Not sure if this will survive to the next release-- depends on whether in so doing I broke other things of importance.